# Sufficient conditions for series to converge in Banach spaces

Tags: solution-verification, normed-spaces, banach-spaces, alternative-proof

I would like to know if the following is true : consider the series $\sum_{n\geq 1}x_n$ in a Banach space, denote $s_n= \sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k$ the partial sum and assume that $\sum_{n\geq 1}\lVert x_n\rVert < \infty$. Then the series  $\sum_{n\geq 1}x_n$ is convergent and

$
\left\lVert\sum_{n\geq 1}x_n\right\rVert\leq\sum_{n\geq 1}\lVert x_n\rVert
$

I think this is true because : the sequence $v_n =\sum_{k=1}^{n}\lVert x_k\rVert $ converge in $\mathbb{R}$ since it is an increasing and bounded sequence and therefore it is a Cauchy sequence.  Now consider $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that

$
m>n>N\implies \lVert v_m - v_n \rVert <\epsilon
$

Since $\lVert s_m - s_n\rVert = \lVert \sum_{k=n+1}^{m}x_k\rVert \leq\sum_{k=n+1}^{m}\lVert x_k\rVert < \epsilon$ this shows that $s_n$ is also a Cauchy sequence, since we are in a Banach space, this shows the convergence of $s_n$ and therefore of the series $\sum_{n\geq 1}x_n$. The last inequality just follow from the triangle inequality and by taking the limit.

Is this seems right ? Don't hesitate to propose your proof !

Thank you !

Comment: We say $\sum x_n$ is absolutely convergent when $\sum \|x_n\| < \infty$. It does imply convergence, and even something stronger, convergence under every rearrangement. However, in the infinite-dimensional case, we can always find a series $\sum x_n$ convergent under every rearrangement, but not absolutely (I find that very interesting).

Comment: This concept was unknown for me until your comment. Thank you a lot !

Comment: Not sure if this is not too advanced for you, but there's a cool book called "Sequences and series in Banach spaces" by Diestel which talks about pretty much anything relating to series in Banach spaces. You might find it interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks perfect to me. In fact the reciprocal is true, a normed space is Banach if and only if every convergent sequence is absolutely convergent. Take a Cauchy sequence $(x_k)\subset E$. Then you can find a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ such that $||x_{n_{k+1}}-x_{n_k}|| < 2^{-k}$. Let $y_k = x_{n_{k+1}}-x_{n_k}$. Then $\sum ||y_k||<\sum 2^{-k}<+\infty$, is absolutely convergent and, by hypothesys, it converges. But $\sum_{k=1}^N y_k = x_{n_N} - x_{n_1}$ and hence $x_k$ has a convergent subsequence. But since $x_k$ is Cauchy, the whole sequence is convergent.

Comment: Thank you very muck for this powerfull insight !! I was not aware of this. There is just a little typo I think in the second line (iff every absolutely convergent sequence is convergent)